# Como puedo obtener e identificar la variable declarada de los JButton al hacer un ActionPerformed?

Tags: java, java-swing, variables, jbutton

Al hacer ActionPerformed en mis Jbuttons quisiera que me llamara  la variable del botton que presione,[image: A estas variables me refiero]

Comment: Obtienes una referencia al botón con el método `getSource()` de ActionEvent.

Comment: debes inicializar tu boton, si no te dara npe.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.